# How to calculate how much data is being transferred over cloud each month in AWS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are using AWS for our infra requirement, and for billing and costing purpose we need to know the exact amount of data transferred to our EC2 instances for a particular client. Is there any such utility available in AWS or how should I approach this problem.

Our Architecture is simple we have a api server which is a `Node.js®` server on one of the ec2 instance, this talks to the db server which is a `MongoDB®` on another ec2, apart from this we also have a web application server which runs angular web application in `Node.js®` again.

Currently we don't use `ELB` and we Identified the client by there login informations i.e the organisation id in the `JWT Token`.

Comment: Start by describing your system architecture and how your client connects. Do they make direct TCP connections or use HTTP? Do you use an ELB? How do you identify your clients? Access tokens? Whitelisted IPs? Something else? All of these points directly affect the answer.

Comment: Updated the question with architecture, do let me know in case if any other information is required.

Comment: Do you use an ELB? How do you identify your clients? Access tokens? Whitelisted IPs? Something else?

Comment: Added the information, could you help me with the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your current architecture, you will need to create some form of Node middleware that extracts the client ID and `content-length` from the request (and/or response) and writes them to persistent storage. Within the AWS ecosystem, you could write to [DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Introduction.html), or [Kinesis](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/introduction.html), or even [SQS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/Welcome.html). Outside the AWS ecosystem you could write to a relational DB, or perhaps the console log with some form of log agent to move the information to persistent store.

However, capturing the data here has a few issues:

- Other than logging to the console, it adds time to each request.
- If logging to the console, there will be a time delay between the actual request and the time that the log is shipped to persistent storage. If the machine crashes in that interval you've lost data.
- When using AWS services you must be prepared for rate limiting (this is one area where SQS is better than Kinesis or DynamoDB).
- Regardless of the approach you use, you will have to write additional code to process the logs.

A better approach, IMO, would be to add the client ID to the URL and an ELB for front-end load distribution. Then turn on [request logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/access-log-collection.html) and do after-the-fact analysis of the logs using [AWS Athena](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/what-is.html) or some other tool.

Comment: thanks a ton this sounds like an ideal solution to me. I will implement this and update. Thanks for taking time to write such detailed solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you run these EC2 instances in VPC, you can use [VPC Flow Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/flow-logs.html) to get insight into how much data each of the instances transfers.

Comment: This has the potential to be a good answer, but it needs explanation. Start with what a flow log looks like (I think an example is in the doc) and how the OP would extract the information needed to bill the customer.

Comment: And you should explain how the analysis changes if an ELB is in the mix.